# submit button is not working in simple html form - flask server

Tags: javascript, python, html, flask, postman

**My Submit Button in HTML/CSS/JS is not working.
Here I attached HTML code
However, I tested my flask server in postman but in simple HTML form submit button is not working!**
***is it something that is I missed in HTML or in JS ?
Please help me with this problem.***

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>Banglore Home Price Prediction</title>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="app.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="app.css">
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="img"></div>
    <form class="form">
        <h2>Area (Square Feet)</h2>
        <input class="area"  type="text" id="uiSqft" class="floatLabel" name="Squareft" value="1000">
        <h2>BHK</h2>
        <div class="switch-field">
            <input type="radio" id="radio-bhk-1" name="uiBHK" value="1"/>
            <label for="radio-bhk-1">1</label>
            <input type="radio" id="radio-bhk-2" name="uiBHK" value="2" checked/>
            <label for="radio-bhk-2">2</label>
            <input type="radio" id="radio-bhk-3" name="uiBHK" value="3"/>
            <label for="radio-bhk-3">3</label>
            <input type="radio" id="radio-bhk-4" name="uiBHK" value="4"/>
            <label for="radio-bhk-4">4</label>
            <input type="radio" id="radio-bhk-5" name="uiBHK" value="5"/>
            <label for="radio-bhk-5">5</label>
        </div>
    </form>
    <form class="form">
        <h2>Bath</h2>
        <div class="switch-field">
            <input type="radio" id="radio-bath-1" name="uiBathrooms" value="1"/>
            <label for="radio-bath-1">1</label>
            <input type="radio" id="radio-bath-2" name="uiBathrooms" value="2" checked/>
            <label for="radio-bath-2">2</label>
            <input type="radio" id="radio-bath-3" name="uiBathrooms" value="3"/>
            <label for="radio-bath-3">3</label>
            <input type="radio" id="radio-bath-4" name="uiBathrooms" value="4"/>
            <label for="radio-bath-4">4</label>
            <input type="radio" id="radio-bath-5" name="uiBathrooms" value="5"/>
            <label for="radio-bath-5">5</label>
        </div>
            <h2>Location</h2>
        <div>
      <select class="location" name="" id="uiLocations">
        <option value="" disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Choose a Location</option>
            <option>Electronic City</option>
            <option>Rajaji Nagar</option>
      </select>
    </div>
        <button class="submit" onclick="onClickedEstimatePrice()" type="button">Estimate Price</button>
        <div 
            id="uiEstimatedPrice" class="result">   <h2></h2> 
        </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: There is no submit button, for your forms, if this '<button class="submit" onclick="onClickedEstimatePrice()" type="button">Estimate Price</button>' is the submit button provide us the JS code for the onClick function.

Answer (score 0):

you need to add action and method to your form tag like:

```html
<form class="form" method="get" action="/your_url/">
....
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to you the default handling of form submitting, you would need to add the `method` (check your postman call to see the method) and `action` (the URL you used to test the call in postman) attributes to your form, as well as changing the type of button to `submit` rather than `button`.

But since you passed on `onclick` handler to your button, I assume you want to do  a custom submit handler. Your best bet is to add an `onsubmit` handler to your form and do the logic there. No need for `method` and `action` here.

```
<form class="form" onsubmit="onFormSubmit(event)">
...
function onFormSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault(); // disable default behavior of submitting
    // access form element values
    // replace elementName with the actual value of the "name" attribute
    // remember to assign unique names to the elements
    console.log(event.target.elements.[elementName].value);
}
```